# How to exclude sidebar from pages?

Tags: pages, sidebar, exclude

I put some page id's in exclude page in appearance -> widget -> pages -> left sidebar. But these pages still exist in sidebar which is not to.

Site: http://goo.gl/ek63ye

Here's the code of left sidebar

```
 <?php 
 global $post, $accesspress_ray_options;
 $accesspress_ray_settings = get_option( 'accesspress_ray_options',    $accesspress_ray_options );
if(is_front_page()){
$post_id = get_option('page_on_front');
}else{
$post_id = $post->ID;
}
$post_class = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'accesspress_ray_sidebar_layout', true );

if($post_class=='left-sidebar' || $post_class=='both-sidebar' ){
?>
<div id="secondary-left" class="widget-area left-sidebar sidebar">
    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- #secondary -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: If you activate default WP theme, do you see the same? Maybe the query is interrupted by any code.

Comment: Are you referring to use of a plugin?